# How to get current version of Android Wear?

Tags: android, version, wear-os

I want to get the `Android Wear version` (e.g. 1.5.0) the application is running in the same manner

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

does for mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know this to adapt your app's functionality, you're better off checking the SDK level on the device, the same as you would on an Android phone or tablet. As you probably know, you do this with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

For example, Wear 2.0 is based on Nougat, and 1.5 on Marshmallow, so you can do a comparison like

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
```

to determine if the watch is running Wear 1.x or 2.0+.

If you **really** need to know the Wear version number, you can get that, but it's a bit more involved:

```
try {
    PackageManager pkgMgr = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo pkgInfo = pkgMgr.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.wearable.app", 0);
    String wearVersion = pkgInfo.versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Can't load PackageInfo for Android Wear app");
}
```

This will give you a value like `1.5.0.3505725` or `2.0.0.141602697`, from which you can parse out as many digits as you're interested in.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: this returns 'Home App' version not for 'Wear OS by Google'.